# Using itertools for recursive function application

Tags: python, functional-programming, iterator, generator, python-itertools

I need a Python function `iterate(f, x)` that creates an iterator returning the values x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), etc (like, e.g., [Clojure's `iterate`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/iterate)).  First of all, I was wondering: Does this already exist somewhere in the standard library and I'm only missing it?  Of course it's easy enough to implement with a generator:

```
def iterate(f, x):
    while True:
        yield x
        x = f(x)
```

Just out of curiosity: Is there a more functional way to do this in Python, e.g. with some itertools or functools magic?

In Python 3.3 this would work

```
def iterate(f, x):
    return accumulate(repeat(x), lambda acc, _ : f(acc))
```

but looks like an abuse to me.  Can I do this more nicely?

Comment: I'd say the `accumulate()` version is just fine. *Both* versions are just fine.

Comment: What I really find strange about the `accumulate()` version is the need for `repeat(x)` or something similar, because x is really only needed *once* as a seed for the computation.

Comment: @embee Now that you mention it, I find that weird as well. Prob best as the first solution

Comment: As one of the Haskell snobs mentioned by @Ned, I'd just like to say that there is a nice way of producing `iterate` from a _single_ initial value: by using an [anamorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) (which is essentially the opposite of `reduce`).

Comment: That was essentially what I was looking for, @phg, that's why I used the word 'recursive'.  But how would you express it in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be something in itertools that does what you want, but itertools is a deep treasure chest, so I could have missed something.

Your generator code looks great.  I don't know why you'd write it with accumulate unless you were playing an absurd game of code golf, or you were trying to impress Haskell snobs.  Write your function so that it is readable, understandable, and maintainable.   No need to be overly clever.

Comment: You're absolutely right and I would never even have thought about the bizarre `accumulate` version before writing up this post. I was genuinely wondering if I was missing a nice, succinct way to use itertools.  
I find myself turning functions into iterators (like here or in the `tabulate` example from the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from time to time and wondered what the most pythonic way to do it would be.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [anamorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) (or *unfold*) to simplify the definition of `iterate`, and to use only one starting value. Here's an implementation I once used, based on a quite well-known [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.125):

```
def ana(build, predicate):
    def h(x):
        if predicate(x):
            return
        else:
            a, b = build(x)
            yield a
            for i in h(b):
                yield i
            # with newer syntax: 
            # yield from h(b)
    return h
```

Implementing `iterate` with `ana` then looks like this:

```
def iterate(f, x):
    return ana(lambda x: (x, f(x)), lambda _: False)(x)
```

No itertools, though... And I agree that this isn't the most readable variant. In fact, it is rather cryptic.

---

UPDATE: There's an easier version, which even looks quite nice. It's taken from [here](http://billmill.org/python_roman.html):

```
def unfold(f, x):
    while True:
        w, x = f(x)
        yield w
```

And that gives you:

```
def iterate(f, x):
    return unfold(lambda y: (y, f(y)), x)
```

Comment: I like this one.  Interestingly, this `unfold` is structured exactly as my original `iterate` generator, but gains a whole new level of abstraction and generality because f now returns pairs instead of a single value. Nice.